# joomla 3.2 backend javascript error

Tags: javascript, php, apache, joomla, nginx

I have two sites on joomla 3.2.3. On both, in backend, buttons like save, edit (material, module, menu...) don`t work. The sites were deployed by akeeba kickstart. On development site all worked. Now, if I fetch a new backup (from web) and install it on extra configured centos 6 local server with php 5.3.3, nginx and apache, they work. So the files should be all good. The error in the javascript console (Firebug) by pressing a button is:

```
TypeError: b.task is undefined
(site)/media/system/js/core.js
Line 4
```

going to create new menu:

```
TypeError: b is null
(site)/modules/mod_roknavmenu/fields/childtype.js
Line 14
```

or on selecting a menu type:

```
TypeError: document.id(...) is null
(site)/administrator/index.php?option=com_menus&view=item&menutype=mainmenu&layout=edit
Line 335
```

So where have I to search for the problem? Maybe hosting provider settings?
Host is centos 6 with php 5.3.3 and nginx (serving static content, js files also). Permissions are good and I tried other deployment methods(direct ftp, ftp zip with server-side extraction).

Comment: Have you checked the forums at RocketTheme?

Comment: Maybe you will have more luck asking on the joomla steck exchange site : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes. I will try both  suggestions. Seems to be something with the web server, well, on windows wamp and linux server they are working. indeed, both sites use rockettheme templates...

Answer (score 0):

**TypeError: b is null  - Joomla 3.0 Component JS Error in Backend
Update 2 - Figured it out - as noted in the backwards compatible page, I had to add the 'id="adminForm" to my form. 
Add 'id="adminForm"’ into admin form.**

Answer (score 0):

I have already forgotten, that I asked here. To whom it may concern:

These errors are caused by not-serving JavaScript if apache and nginx are working together. Add to your nginx static files settings following: `application-text/javascript  .js` Second thing: JS and js are different names, the nginx separates by register!

Add all kinds of mime-types applying to JavaScript: `text/plain, script/javascript, application/x-javascript` et al!